# Handling multiple subclasses of UITableViewCell within a table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building a `UITableView` within a detail view controller. Some aspects of this table view include:

- Multiple cell styles are defined with identifiers/subclasses in Interface Builder; for example, `PhotoCell` and `InfoCell`, both of which extend `UITableViewCell`.
- Cells are dynamically generated. If certain values are missing from the detail view controller, those cells will not be displayed.
- Within each subclass of `UITableViewCell`, I've created a `static createCell()` method that returns an initialized, populated cell using `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

### Questions

1. What is best practice for building the table view in this scenario?
2. In my approach below, is it acceptable (or even useful) to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in a method other than the data source delegate methods?

### Current Approach

The approach I've taken is to define a `source` property containing an array of the cells. I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it.

**PlaceViewController+UITableViewDataSource.swift**

```
extension PlaceViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    var source: [UITableViewCell] {
        get {
            var cells = [UITableViewCell]()

            if let cell = SummaryCell.createCell(tableView, text: place?.generalInfo) {
                cells.append(cell)
            }
            // ^^ repeat above for each cell in table           

            return cells
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return source.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return source[indexPath.row]
    }

}
```

**SummaryCell.swift**

```
class SummaryCell : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var summaryLabel: UILabel!

    static func createCell(tableView: UITableView, text: String?) -> SummaryCell? {
        if let text = text {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SummaryCell") as! SummaryCell
            cell.summaryLabel.text = text
            return cell
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: This approach seems like it will break with cell reuse.  You should call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using different cells for a table, might as well do a conditional check or a switch what type of cell you need in a particular index then try to deque if that kind of cell has been created - if not initialize a new one.

Also, looking at your code, you're creating a new array of cells whenever the call for cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, which is not good.